# Building Weather Forecast from JSON with optionals

Tags: json, swift

I am looking for the best way of parsing JSON in Swift 2.0.

I have this JSON

> ```
> {
>   "latitude": 37.8267,
>   "longitude": -122.423,
>   "currently": {
>     "time": 1440110395,
>     "summary": "Clear"
>   }
> }
> ```

and field `summary` is NOT always visible in response.

My model object and parsing method:

```
enum JSONErrorType: ErrorType {
  case InvalidJson
}

struct WeatherForecast {
  let date: NSDate
  let summary: String?
  let latitude: Double
  let longitude: Double

  init(date: NSDate, summary: String?, latitude: Double, longitude: Double) {
    self.latitude = latitude
    self.longitude = longitude
    self.date = date
    self.summary = summary
  }

  static func fromJSON(json: AnyObject) throws -> WeatherForecast {
    guard let dict = json as? NSDictionary,
      let latitude = dict["latitude"] as? Double,
      let longitude = dict["longitude"] as? Double,
      let curr_dict = dict["currently"] as? NSDictionary,
      let timestamp = curr_dict["time"] as? NSTimeInterval else {
      throw JSONErrorType.InvalidJson
    }
    let date = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: timestamp)
    if let summary = curr_dict["summary"] as? String {
      return WeatherForecast(date: date, summary: summary, latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
    } else {
      return WeatherForecast(date: date, summary: nil, latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)

    }
  }
}
```

I can't use `guard` because the `summary` property is optional. `if let` works here but I have two returns which doesn't look very good. Also if I will have more optionals fields, the code gets messy.

Comment: @Malachi Why did you edit the title? It's JSON parsing in swift 2.0 and it has nothing to do with weather API. I could use any other API in this example.

Comment: As we all want to make our code more efficient or improve it in one way or another, try to write a title that summarizes what your code does.  For examples of good titles, check out [Best of Code Review 2014 - Best Question Title Category](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/3883/23788) You may also want to read [How to get the best value out of Code Review - Asking Questions](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/2438/41243).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Remember optionals.

Let's start with answering your primary concern: what do I do with the `summary` field?

You've already appropriately set up a constructor which takes a `String?` argument for `summary`.  But your particular code never takes advantage of this fact, does it?

> ```
> if let summary = curr_dict["summary"] as? String
> ```

Let's break down what's going on here piece by piece.

- `curr_dict["summary"]` returns an `AnyObject?`.  It makes no assumptions about the type, since `curr_dict` is an `NSDictionary`.  It either returns whatever value is at that key, or `nil` if the key doesn't exist.
- `as? String` tries to cast that value as a `String`.  If the value was `nil` or if it can't be cast as a string, it returns `nil`, otherwise it returns `String`.
- `let summary =` declares the variable called `summary`, whose type is determined by the return of everything to the right.  Since the top of the right-side's stack is `as? String`, which can return `nil` or a `String`, then the return type is `String?`.
- `if let` casts an optional type (`String?`) as a non-optional type (`String`) if it can, otherwise it enters the `else` block.

So... we can get rid of the `if let` part, and just make ourselves an optional string, right?

```
let summary = curr_dict["summary"] as? String
return WeatherForecast(date: date, summary: summary, latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
```

---

## But wait, there's more!

> ```
> guard let dict = json as? NSDictionary, // ...
> ```

We should prefer to use Swift types over Objective-C types when that makes sense.  And here is a place where it does.  What we want is a `[String:Any]`.

```
guard let dictionary = json as? [String:Any], // ...
```

---

#### Encapsulate.

We should also prefer encapsulation.  It doesn't make particular sense to have a `latitude` and `longitude` property.  What we need is a type that encapsulates these, as they're just two parts of describing one thing: location.

The easiest solution would be simply importing `CoreLocation` and either using `CLLocationCooridinate2D` or `CLLocation`.  The downside to this, however, is that any class that uses our struct has to import `CoreLocation` in order to use this property, but we can easily get around this with a `typealias`:

```
typealias WeatherForecastLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D
```

And now we replace our `latitude` and `longitude` properties with a property of type `WeatherForecastLocation`.

---

#### Informative Errors

So, `JSONErrorType.InvalidJSON`... how useful is this?  It's an enum with a single case, just so we have something to throw.  We can be so much more informative.

First of all, two types of valid top-level JSON objects.  Dictionary or array.  So any method we write to parse JSON will expect one of these two types, so the first error will be the JSON not being that type.  That gives use two errors right off the bat (and let's grab some better names here):

```
enum JSONParseError: ErrorType {
    case ExpectedArrayNotFound
    case ExpectedDictionaryNotFound
}
```

If we are looking for JSON with a top-level object of dictionary, and we don't find it, we throw `ExpectedDictionaryNotFound`.  It doesn't matter what it looked like.  But this is already more informative... we couldn't even manage to get past the first level.

Now, what's another sort of JSON parsing error?  Missing keys.  But we don't want to simply be that generic.  Let's specify what key is missing, shall we?  Swift enums can have [associated values](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH12-ID148).  With our `MissingKey` error, we should use a `String` associated value to identify the missing key.  Or `enum` now looks like this:

```
enum JSONParseError: ErrorType {
    case ExpectedArrayNotFound
    case ExpectedDictionaryNotFound
    case MissingKey(String)
}
```

We also have an error case for when the type of the value doesn't match what we expect.  For this, we want to specify the key that's problematic and specify the type that we expect it to be, so let's associate a tuple of two strings:

```
enum JSONParseError: ErrorType {
    case ExpectedArrayNotFound
    case ExpectedDictionaryNotFound
    case MissingKey(String)
    case InvalidTypeForKey(String,String)
}
```

So, the first string specifies the key, and the second string is a message something like `"Expected Int"`, `"Expected Array"`.

Now... the last thing we can do here that's probably quite helpful... return the JSON that was passed in with error.

```
enum JSONParseError: ErrorType {
    case ExpectedArrayNotFound(Any)
    case ExpectedDictionaryNotFound(Any)
    case MissingKey(String,Any)
    case InvalidTypeForKey(String,String,Any)
}
```